# Datetime con default en fecha actual

Tags: mysql

Me pidieron cambiar una columna de date a datetime y que por defecto tenga la fecha actual ya cambie el tipo de dato pero no consigo encontrar el comando para la default ayuda porfavor.

[image: en teoría tengo que hacer que ve_fventa tenga la fecha actual.]

Comment: Podrías poner tu código para ver tu avance y en base a eso poder dar una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probaste con algo parecido a esto? si usas phpmyadmin o similar es más fácil.

ALTER TABLE `tabla` CHANGE `campo_fecha` `campo_fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;